# Guidance Automation Toolkit

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

How is guidance automation toolkit used to created VS project and item templates? How can create a recipe using that.

Comment: do you try to google? or read documentation?

Comment: couldnt find anything helpful.... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [starting here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/aa718950.aspx) Or this [google book](http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=s9xKkrmjgukC&pg=PA152&lpg=PA152&dq=gat+creating+recipes&source=bl&ots=NgZfkfA3IX&sig=XeITHv6YOmzLAFSp7zsi2Nv5t-A&hl=en&ei=zgWQSqvqMInQtgOf_40M&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7#v=onepage&q=gat%20creating%20recipes&f=false). And [this](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2006/09/how-to-create-guidance-package.html) was always a classic